# how can I read the user comments entered for a Facebook page in a MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to read my app comments, but I don't know how? there is no correct/complete sample.

```
[CanvasAuthorize(Permissions = "user_about_me")]
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        var client = new FacebookWebClient(FacebookWebContext.Current.AccessToken);
        dynamic result = client.Get("19292868552_118464504835613/comments");
        ViewBag.result = result;
    }
```

and on view, try to read like this:

```
foreach (dynamic comment in ViewBag.result)
{
    @comment.id
    <text><br /></text>
}
```

please help how can I read the user comments entered for a Facebook page in a MVC application.

Comment: What does "no luck" mean?  What does the response look like?

Comment: Thanks @jfar for your response, I figured it out and I'll add it here later. probably you know that: client.get("{PageID}/feed") and got the response fields from https://graph.facebook.com, Thanks, Pedram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you know in Facebook you can create your own page and that page has an ID in URL.
Here is the codes for the controller:

```
[CanvasAuthorize(Permissions = "user_about_me")]
    public ActionResult Comments()
    {
        var client = new FacebookWebClient(FacebookWebContext.Current.AccessToken);
        dynamic feeds = client.Get("{PageID}/feed");


        ViewBag.feeds = feeds;
        return View();
    }
```

and the codes for your view:

```
<table>
@foreach (dynamic myFeed in ViewBag.feeds.data)
{

    if (myFeed.type == "status" && myFeed.from.id != "{PageID}")
    { 

    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="@HomeController.GetPictureUrlSmall(myFeed.from.id)" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">@myFeed.from.name</span><br />
            @myFeed.message
        </td>
    </tr>

    }
}
</table> 
@{
string strNext = ViewBag.feeds.paging.next;
string strPrevious = ViewBag.feeds.paging.previous;
}
<a href="@strPrevious" >Previous</a>
<br />
<a href="@strNext" >Next</a>
```

A function for getting the users pictures:

```
public static string GetPictureUrlSmall(string faceBookId)
    {
        WebResponse response = null;
        string pictureUrl = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(string.Format("http://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture?type=small", faceBookId));
            response = request.GetResponse();
            pictureUrl = response.ResponseUri.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //? handle
        }
        finally
        {
            if (response != null) response.Close();
        }
        return pictureUrl;
    }
```

I hope it will be helpful for some developers but I still have problem with pagination. I didn't find a handy solution for that. Thanks, Pedram

Comment: @NathanTotten can you please give me a solution for facebook comments pagination. I'm using mvc 3 and I need to catch Json after click on the next.